# Merge statement in SnowFlake seems to be writing too many rows. Is there a way to improve this?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I am doing a basic merge statement to update a set of rows in a table.  The table has 1B rows and is 160GB. The table is clustered using a TenantId column as the clustering key. This column has 10k different values with fairly even distribution.

The data I am merging in are just updates, and include 1M records targeting a subset of those tenant IDs (~500). The merge joins this source to the target based on TenantId (the cluster key of the target) and a recordID.

The result of the merge correctly lists the number of rows that were updated, but is taking longer than I would expect.  If I look at the query execution details, I see that the Merge operation in the plan (which takes up almost all the time compared to the table scans / joins) has "Bytes scanned" and "Bytes written" both equal to the 160GB size of my table.

The bytes written seems concerning there. Is there a way to get it to focus the writes on micro-partitions relevant to the records being touched? It doesn't seem like it should need to write the full size of the table.

Cluster depth for the table: 1.0208

Cluster information for the table:
{
"cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(TENANTID)",
"total_partition_count" : 29827,
"total_constant_partition_count" : 29646,
"average_overlaps" : 0.0323,
"average_depth" : 1.0208,
"partition_depth_histogram" : {
"00000" : 0,
"00001" : 29643,
"00002" : 19,
"00003" : 49,
"00004" : 55,
"00005" : 17,
"00006" : 9,
"00007" : 25,
"00008" : 5,
"00009" : 5,
"00010" : 0,
"00011" : 0,
"00012" : 0,
"00013" : 0,
"00014" : 0,
"00015" : 0,
"00016" : 0
}
}

Comment: By "partitioned by TenantId" I assume that means there's a clustering key defined on it. Can you share the clustering key definition and the output of system$clustering_information?

Comment: Yes, that was the clustering key.  Updated the question to clarify that and include clustering informaiton.

Comment: Ran the query again, and had better performance and less bytes written.  The bytes written now is for ~65GB, and the input included 500 out of 10k tenants.  I think the difference from my first run is that perhaps reclustering has happened since then.  This is better, but still writing 40% of the table when I updated 1% of the rows and touched 5% of my values of the cluster key.

Comment: The clustering on the table looks very good. You're probably already aware that since object storage is immutable, an update to a single row in a micro-partition requires an entire rewrite of the micro-partition. If only 5% of the TenantId have updates but it's affecting 40% of the table bytes, it's probably because some of the TenantId values have many more rows than the others and are filling several micro-partitions. Updates to those TenantId rows could be affecting a lot of micro-partitions.

Comment: I suspected that was the case regarding updating full micro-partitions, but thank you for confirming. As far as the data distribution, this is actually just a POC setup currently each tenant has the same number of records. So still surprised by the number of micro-partitions being impacted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to understand what is happening underneath and how Micro-partitions work to understand what is going on.

Snowflake tables appear mutable (allows updates) but underneath it is made up of immutable files. When executing an update to an existing record the files that represent that record are written to time time travel as a record in its previous state before the update. And the new record is written to the active micro-partitions; that's right, an update will create micropartitions, those visible to the active micro-partitions and existing ones are committed to time travel.

This is why insert-only modelling and architecture paradigms are so much more efficient than those that allow updates. Updates even in traditional RDBMs are expensive operations and in Big Data platforms this is pretty much impossible.

Yes Snowflake supports updates, but it is up to you to use the platform efficiently, and yes that even includes how you model on the platform.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I guess what I'm missing is why such a high % of micro partitions are being touched (and thus fully replaced) given the clustering and the fact that the updates target a small subset of the cluster key.